# Remount /system from a system app;

Tags: java, android, system, mount

I want to remount /system as RW, from a system priv-app without su. How to do this programmatically? Will just executing a shell command with Runtime.getruntime().exec() it os.writebytes() do? Or will it require more specific permissions or commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  There's no system permission that will allow you to remount a disk.  That requires actual root.

Comment: Hi, I just searched through about GID. I didn't manage to obtain much information, but only a single result showed remounting /system with GID(1000) (which is the ID of system apps). And, doesn't the system apps have to write to system now and then? Anyway I guess the best way is to try myself. Thanks!